# Enterprise VNC client?

Tags: network, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm a little new to Enterprise Mac management but have 10 years experience as a Mac tech.  I am in charge of deployment of 3k + macs for a LARGE international corporation.  We are using Casper Suite.

To use VNC right now I have to ask people to get their IP then enable sharing so I can ask for permission.  For some people, this is really annoying since they are "higher ups" and only has a couple minutes at a time.

My question is this.  Is there a good Enterprise solution to VNC quickly?  Maybe where I have a special login that either automatically logs me into their computer or asks them for permission without having them go through the annoyance of getting me the info and checking the box.

FYI, I was told that automatically checking that "anyone can request access" would be a security loophole so I can have that checked at deployment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven’t used it much, but I have worked in an environment with 500+ Macs and we used ARD (Apple Remote Desktop) with them. Have you tried looking into ARD?

Comment: Let's which better solutions will show up in the answers. Nevertheless it might help to explain to higher ups (and others) that these steps actually prevent misuse and protect them from random strangers accessing their screens without them noticing it.

Comment: The problem with ARD is that we have SOOOOO many networks and virtual networks in tons of different buildings/countries that ARD has a hard time detecting them AND gaining access.  With VNC, all I need is the IP and everything works great.